# Why Muhammed is the last prophet and God doesn't send anyone else?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, allah, prophets

Looking at the fact that we always need guidance from god, I wonder why God decided not to ever send any prophet again??  just think how good it would be when we could ask anything from a prophet and be sure that answer is 100% correct and will of God and act upon it, or where he could lead the all believers instead of misguided sects killing others.

Comment: Very similar to this question: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/3022/frequent-change-in-message-from-the-creator-god-allah/

Comment: A sect of Islam truly believes that Allah swt has not abandoned his believers and is guided by one Imam - descendent of Rasulullah swt - the guiding star for His followers

Answer (score 2):

First of all, Allah is best of all planners. We might think that our logical reason is fair enough to be very good overall. So in this case, we have to believe on unseen and trusting on the fact that, Allah is best of all planners, He will surely have something good in it.

but personally, the logic is very simple. The need for prophet is like we need teachers to teach us to make us some a doctor or engineer. like teachers teach us and make us more mature with classes after classes. First its class 1, then 2 then so on till 10, then college, then university,then P.hD. Same is the case with humanity. Humanity is now at such a level, that it does not need any Prophet to tech us about the message of Allah. Message of Allah is already clear enough for whole humanity till end of world, and there is no need for any prophet to come and tell us about that message himself.

Imagine, even if we have a prophet, still the wrong people will find way out to twist his teachings and will make sects.

Sects are formed by those, who are worst of creation, who worship their Ego, do it for money, popularity or many selfish reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Lets divide the time according to concept of prophets.

1. The first human is created
2. The first human is sent to Earth
3. The first human is also the first prophet
4. Mankind reproduce
5. The true belief is corrupted
6. Another prophet is sent to correct the belief
7. Mankind divided into groups
8. Go to 5 for many loops
9. The last prophet is sent
10. The true belief is abandoned (not corrupted but abandoned this time)
11. Apocalypse

The Earth has an end, so the prophets should have an end. We are in the time of after 9, before/inside 10. Why didn't we born before? Destiny. Some people should born in the time of number 10, and we are a part of that group. You may call it luck or unluck, but there has to be a last prophet and we were simply born after him.